# Fontsize determination

Tags: conditionals, fontsize

We usually point out explicitly or not normalfont size in `\documentclass[11pt]{article}` etc. `11pt` may be absent here explicitly. Which variable contains this 11 or 10, 12pt?. I need get it in a tex-file for some `\if`... constructions

Comment: Recently I asked a similar question, but regarding current color instead of font size. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146096/is-it-possible-to-detect-the-current-color-in-a-pgfplot-drawing, I expected that some variable would hold that information, but the answer was more complicated than just that.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for `\@ptsize`. It is defined by the standard document classes as `0` for the `10pt` class option, as `1` for the `11pt` option and as `2` for the `12pt` option.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\showfontsize}{Fontsize: 1\@ptsize\,pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\showfontsize

\end{document}
```

Here's the relevant definition in the class files:

```
\if@compatibility
\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}
\else
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
```

`\@ptsize` is also defined by the [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes (`scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, `scrbook`).

As pointed out by egreg: The [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class "has `\@memptsize` that expands to the “real” thing (10, 11, and so on); the [AMS](http://ctan.org/pkg/amslatex) classes have `\@mainsize` for the same thing. The [`extsizes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) package instead redefines `\@ptsize` to contain the full number."

Comment: You could note that `memoir` has `\@memptsize` that expands to the “real” thing (10, 11, and so on); the AMS classes have `\@mainsize` for the same thing. The `extsizes` package instead redefines `\@ptsize` to contain the full number.

Comment: After `\normalsize`, examine `\f@size`. This is a macro holding the normalfont size, without the `pt`. But be aware that, for historical reasons, the `11pt` option sets the `\f@size` to `10.95` in most classes.

Comment: It seems to me that \@ptsize is not a constant in the latex-word. There are packages which change it. This is a tex-barbarism however! What purpose the latex has been created for? This is a principal point why i dislike to use packages. If one wants to be well make everything yourself

Comment: @maximav quite right.  and if you're good enough (and also a good communicator) you attract followers.  and the followers do the same as you did.  and so ad infinitum...

Comment: as @egreg points out, the ams classes do have `\@mainsize` but they also have `\@ptsize` applied "in the usual manner".  the reason for `\@mainsize` is that `amsart` also supports options `[8pt]` and `[9pt]` (not actually advertised, but created mainly for internal use), and in that context, `\@ptsize=9` doesn't make any sense.  (but the original use of `\@ptsize` is retained for historical reasons and the "appearance of compatibility".  many basic latex decisions don't "scale" or adapt easily, so workarounds are necessary.  please don't blame publishers for doing that.)