# Is it possible to detect the "current color"? (for example in a pgfplot drawing?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

Is there a code to deduce the current color of a PGF plot to which a node is associated? Better yet, is it possible to get the RGB decomposition as well?

```
...
addplot coordinates{ (0,0) (1,1) } node{ "get-RGB-color-of-the-00-11-line here" };
...
```

The reason is that I have a `pdfmarginpar` note, and I want the color of the annotation to match the color (at least approximately) to that of the plotted line. As in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfmarginpar}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(0, 0)(1, 1)} 
    node{
       node text
       \pdfmarginpar[
        color={[1 0 1]} % some arbitrary color, GOAL: color="current pgfplot's plot color"
       ]{note text} 
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

("node text" has the right color by default, the marginpar not.) Of course the comment appears in purple instead of the blue (automatic color chosen by pgfplot in this case).

[image: purplenotblue]

---

**EDIT**: Thank you @percusse for putting everything together and @masu to point out the underlying mechanism. Here it is to solution applied to my original MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfmarginpar}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(0, 0)(1, 1)} 
    node{
            node text
        \let\mynotecolor\empty
        \extractcolorspecs{.}{\model}{\mycurrentcolor}
        \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycurrentcolor}{rgb}\mycurrentrgb
        \foreach \x in \mycurrentrgb{\expandafter\xdef\expandafter\mynotecolor{\mynotecolor\space\x}}
        \pdfmarginpar[color={[\mynotecolor]}]{note text}
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In fact it may make sense to (re)define `\pdfmarginpar` to take the current color:

```
% if you know how to use \renewcommand please edit this post
\newcommand{\colorpdfmarginpar}[2][]{
    \let\mynotecolor\empty
    \extractcolorspecs{.}{\model}{\mycurrentcolor}
    \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycurrentcolor}{rgb}\mycurrentrgb
    \foreach \x in \mycurrentrgb{\expandafter\xdef\expandafter\mynotecolor{\mynotecolor\space\x}}
    \pdfmarginpar[color={[\mynotecolor]}, #1]{#2}
}
```

(sorry, I didn't manage to use the `renewcommand`, it seems that I don't know how to use it.)

And then use `\colorpdfmarginpar` to always (by default) match the node to the current color, inside or outside pgfplots. (Color still be overwritten with the explicit `color` option).

Comment: @masu, yes I expect this to be more related to accessing variables of pgfplots rather than something that can be solved with `xcolor` (well, maybe the RGB translation part). `\testcolor` seems to be to display colors. I don't want to match the color manually, but automatically, so that if the color of the plot changes (e.g. due to reordering) then the annotation changes color also.

Comment: sorry, I deleted my pessimist comment because I'd found a solution. I didn't know you seen it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can actually get the current settings via `[current plot style]` scope and then record the desired settings regarding the last style in the `cycle list`. (Thanks to @masu for fixing a bug in the previous version of this answer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pdfmarginpar}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.9,
    margin par settings/.style={%}
        execute at end plot visualization={%}
            \begin{scope}[current plot style]
                \pgfextra{%}
                    \let\mytemp\empty
                    \extractcolorspecs{.}{\model}{\mycolor}
                    \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{rgb}\tmp
                    \foreach \x in \tmp{%}
                        \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\mytemp\expandafter{\mytemp\space\x}
                    }
                }
            \end{scope}
        },
        execute at end plot={%}
                     \node[draw] at (current plot end) {%}
                                node text \protect\pdfmarginpar[Open=true,
                                                                color={[\mytemp]}
                                                               ]{note text}%
            };
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot+[margin par settings] {x^2};
    \addplot+[margin par settings] {10+5*cos(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, I am not very interested in a global setting. Would it be possible to have a code "per addplot", maybe that is incompatible with a `begin/end{scope}`.

Comment: @alfC I don't understand exactly your comment but only the style description is global. The style usage is per addplot as in the example. Just remove one of the `[margin par settings]`. You can make it such that it accepts arguments but I just wanted to try out

Comment: Nevermind, I added exactly what I wanted as a solution to the question (EDIT at the end). I ended up defining a `\colorpdfmarginpar` (see EDIT) that has all this code. Not sure if it a good idea and I couldn't use `renewcommand` to keep the original name (do you know what I did wrong, because it ends up being a recursive erroneous call).

Comment: @percusse really nice (apart from the bug) (+1). May I edit your answer to remove the duplication issue?

Comment: @masu Sure, please do

Comment: @percusse I don't really know why, but `execute at end plot visualization` gets expanded twice, so the note will also be created twice. If I put the text node into `execute at end plot` instead, there'll be only one. (I still couldn't give that +1, because I've run out of votes for today. :) )

Comment: @masu Ha! That's strange indeed I didn't expect that. Thanks for the fix. And nevermind the voting thingy, hanging out here is solving sudoku for me :)

Answer (score 8):

There might be a better way, but here's one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\colorlet{abc}{green!40!yellow}

\extractcolorspec{.}{\colorcurrent}

\extractcolorspec{abc}{\colortest}

\ifx\colortest\colorcurrent Y\else N\fi

\extractcolorspec{black}{\colortest}

\ifx\colortest\colorcurrent Y\else N\fi

If the model is different, but should be checked.

\definecolor{mycmyk}{cmyk}{0.5,0.3,0.3,0.2}

\definecolor{mycmykblack}{cmyk}{0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0}

\extractcolorspecs{.}{\colorcurrentmodel}{\colorcurrent}

\extractcolorspec{mycmyk}{\colortest}

\ifx\colortest\colorcurrent Y\else N\fi

\extractcolorspecs{mycmyk}{\colortestmodel}{\colortest}

\convertcolorspec{\colortestmodel}{\colortest}{\colorcurrentmodel}{\colortestconverted}

\ifx\colortestconverted\colorcurrent Y\else N\fi

\extractcolorspec{mycmykblack}{\colortest}

\ifx\colortest\colorcurrent Y\else N\fi

\extractcolorspecs{mycmykblack}{\colortestmodel}{\colortest}

\convertcolorspec{\colortestmodel}{\colortest}{\colorcurrentmodel}{\colortestconverted}

\ifx\colortestconverted\colorcurrent Y\else N\fi

\end{document}
```

This prints out `N`,`Y`,`N`,`N`,`N`,`Y` as expected.

---

Explanation:

- `\extractcolorspec` extracts the color specification of `#1` into `#2` as a string
- `\extractcolorspecs` does similar things, but divides the string into color model (`#2`) and the definition (`#3`)
- `\convertcolorspecs` is for converting a color (`#2`) from one color model (`#1`) to another (`#3`)... storing the definition in `#4`
- `\ifx` is for doing the comparison
- `.` is for referencing the current color

---

**EDIT**: A solution for your problem using `xpatch` instead of `xstring`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfmarginpar}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\begin{document}

{
%print ABC in red, and extract the color
\color{red}ABC\extractcolorspecs{.}{\colorcurrentmodel}{\colorcurrentlocal}
\global\let\colorcurrentglobal\colorcurrentlocal%define global variable?
}

\xpatchcmd{\colorcurrentglobal}{,}{ }{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\colorcurrentglobal}{,}{ }{}{}

\pdfmarginpar[
        color={[\colorcurrentglobal]} % some arbitrary color, GOAL: color="currentcolor"
]{text}
\end{document}
```

Related (if you want to use `xstring` instead of `xpatch`): [Using xstring macros in edef](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146608/using-xstring-macros-in-edef#comment332431_146608)

Comment: `\extractcolorspec` is repeated twice in your explanation, is that a mistake?

Comment: @alf to repeat something else: it's not and it's not. :) The first is `\extractcolorspec` the second have an extra `s` in the end

Comment: Interesting, but First, I can't seem to do anything useful with the `\colorcurrent` variable. For example: `\colorlet{vlt}{red!50!blue}\{\color{vlt}\extractcolorspec{.}{\colorcurrent}}`, how do I use `\colorcurrent`?. I tried using `{\colorcurrent text}` and `{\color{\colorcurrent} test}` with no effect. Second, how can I extract the RGB components, I understand that I can convert from cmyk` to `rgb` with `\convertcolorspec` but how do I extract the R, G and B component as three numbers between 0 and 1 in order to use it in the annotation code `pdfmarginpar{ ... color = [R G B] ...}`?

Comment: @alfC the easiest way I can think of is using the `xstring` package: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\color{red}ABC\extractcolorspecs{.}{\colorcurrentmodel}{\colorcurrent}

\color{black}DEF

\StrSubstitute[2]{\colorcurrent}{,}{ }

\end{document}`

Comment: great, I can extract the string now (for example `1 0 0`) but I have two challenges, 1) `\colorcurrent` seems to be a local variable so if the color detection is contained in `{}` it won't be visible outside that scope (?), I think that is needed for my example use 2) (maybe related), I cannot make use the `\colorcurrent` variable in the `marginpar` since it is the same as having an empty option `color={[]}` which is an error (and leads to a malformed PDF).

Comment: Ithe original post has a MWE. I tried `\gdef` with no luck, I added a second MWE to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @alfC the use of `xstring` would have needed several expansions so I've decided go with a different and much cleaner approach.