# Using xstring macros in edef

Tags: macros, expansion, xstring

I've tried to use `\protect` to make the following `\edef` work but no luck. Can it be done somehow?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\abc{a,b,c}
\edef\result{\StrSubstitute[2]{\abc}{,}{ }}

\result

\end{document}
```

NOTE: I know I can do the same using `etoolbox` or `xpatch` (and I already did that), but became curious about the problem above.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: I had answered prior to your reply here. `;-)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: you can't.

The instruction `\edef` works purely by expansion; no assignment can be performed during an `\edef`: when TeX finds an unexpandable token in `\edef` it passes over it and proceeds with the next token.

So you can't say

```
\newcount\baz
\edef\foo{\advance\baz 1 \number\baz}
```

and hope that `\foo` expands to `1`. It will expand to

```
\advance\baz 1 0
```

because `\advance`, `\baz` and `1` are unexpandable, while `\number` is expandable. Just try it in an interactive session:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013)
**\relax

*\newcount\baz

*\edef\foo{\advance\baz 1 \number\baz}

*\show\foo
> \foo=macro:
->\advance \baz 1 0.
<*> \show\foo
```

With `\StrSubstitute` *several* assignments are made; not only operations on registers are assignments, but also `\def\` and `\let` are.

The correct way to define `\result` to contain the result of the substitution is

```
\StrSubstitute[2]{\abc}{,}{ }[\result]
```

The trailing optional argument can be used in most `xstring` macros.

Here's the test file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\abc{a,b,c}
\StrSubstitute[2]{\abc}{,}{ }[\result]

\texttt{\meaning\result}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've learnt many things from this answer, thank you.