# Using xstring to generate index keys

Tags: macros, expansion, xstring, imakeidx

I have a document containing many instances of an environment with a mandatory argument providing a short "tag." These tags are something like "M04", and I've written a macro using `xstring` which convert this to, e.g., "May!2004". I'd like to use this macro to automatically add an index entry using `imakeidx`.

It seems there are problems at various stages stemming from macro expansion. In the MWE below, I can use `\index{\genkey{M04}}` to add to the index, but it seems that `\genkey` is expanded too late, because "May!2004" appears literally in the index (rather than with 2004 as a sub-entry). I can't get even to this point with the environment - I end up with many complaints about undefined control sequences coming from the xstring package.

I've attempted to use `edef` to get all expansion done with before passing to `\index`, but to no avail - as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146608/using-xstring-macros-in-edef), it is impossible to use `edef` in conjunction with `string`.

Any help on how to get the code below to work as desired would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\newcommand\getmonth[1]{%
  \StrChar{#1}{1}[\firstchar]%
  \IfStrEq{\firstchar}{J}{January}{May}%
}
\newcommand\getyearprefix[1]{%
  \StrChar{#1}{2}[\secondchar]%
  \IfStrEq{\secondchar}{9}{19}{20}%
}
\newcommand{\genkey}[1]{%
    \getmonth{#1}!\getyearprefix{#1}\StrMid{#1}{2}{3}%
}

\newenvironment{entry}[1]{%
  \index{\genkey{#1}}%
}
{}

\begin{document}

\genkey{M04}

\genkey{J98}

\index{\genkey{M04}}

% \begin{entry}{M04}
% Here is the M04 entry
% \end{entry}

% \begin{entry}{J98}
% Here is the J98 entry
% \end{entry}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the keys guaranteed to be one letter followed by two numbers, or might this change as well?

Comment: And what's with the months that have the same initial letter? Is `M` always May, or could it be March?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following defines expandable versions of `\getmonth`, `\getyearprefix` and `\genkey`. The argument must consist of 3 characters (the argument is detokenized).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \getmonth { +m }
  {
    \str_case:nn { #1 }
      {
        { J } { January }
        { F } { February }
        { m } { March }
        { a } { April }
        { M } { May }
        { j } { June }
        { J } { July }
        { A } { August }
        { S } { September }
        { O } { October }
        { N } { November }
        { D } { December }
      }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \getyearprefix { +m }
  {
    \int_case:nn { #1 }
      {
        { 0 } { 20 }
        { 1 } { 20 }
        { 2 } { 19 }
        { 3 } { 19 }
        { 4 } { 19 }
        { 5 } { 19 }
        { 6 } { 19 }
        { 7 } { 19 }
        { 8 } { 19 }
        { 9 } { 19 }
      }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { genkey } { improper-length }
  { The ~ token ~ list ~ has ~ the ~ wrong ~ length ~ ( #1 ) }
\cs_new:Npn \__genkey:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \getmonth { #1 } ! \getyearprefix { #2 } #2 #3
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \genkey { +m }
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \str_count_ignore_spaces:n { #1 } } = 3
      { \exp_after:wN \__genkey:nnn \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }
      {
        \msg_expandable_error:nnf { genkey } { improper-length }
          { \str_count_ignore_spaces:n { #1 } }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentEnvironment { entry } { m }
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \index { \genkey { #1 } }
  }
  {}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\genkey{M04}

\genkey{J98}

% doesn't work, honestly no idea why index doesn't always expand its argument
\index{\genkey{M04}}

\begin{entry}{M04}
Here is the M04 entry
\end{entry}

\begin{entry}{J98}
Here is the J98 entry
\end{entry}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Poor July, will always be shadowed by the mighty January ;-)

Comment: July will never be selected.

Comment: Beautiful! This will motivate me to finally learn expl3. If I understand correctly, this works because unlike xstring, the \getmonth and related macros don't make assignments and are therefore expandable?

Comment: Oh, forgot about the January clash, my bad. Suggestions?

Comment: @srossd correct, in `interface3.pdf` fully expandable macros are marked so you can see what can be declared expandable and what not.